# Sql query for room availability

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have the following tables in my database:
1.`Roomtypes`
2.`Reservations`

`Roomtypes` have the following columns 
`id`,
`product_id`,
`type`,
`total_no_of_rooms`,
`created_at`,
`updated_at`

`Reservation` has the following columns

`id`,

`roomtype_id`,

`customer_id`,

`check_in`,

`check_out`,

`no_of_rooms`,

`created_at`,

`updated_at`,

i need to get the rooms remaining in roomtype table if someone books a room. that is details no of rooms in a specific date,rooms which are not in reservations. can anyun help me with the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess, in the absence of a table `CREATE` script, would be something like:

```
SELECT rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms, 
    IFNULL(SUM(r.no_of_rooms), 0) as "reserved rooms", 
    rt.total_no_of_rooms - IFNULL(SUM(r.no_of_rooms),0) as "rooms available"  
FROM Roomtypes rt 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservation r ON r.roomtype_id = rt.id 
        AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN r.check_in AND r.check_out
GROUP BY rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms
```

This query should get the number of rooms available for each room type now (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`), but you can replace that with any other time stamp, e.g. '2018-05-17 10:00:00'.

To see how many rooms are available within a data range - check-in at 2018-04-11 10:00:00 and latest check-out at 2018-04-12 09:59:59:

```
SELECT rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms, 
  IFNULL(SUM(r.no_of_rooms), 0) as "reserved rooms", 
  rt.total_no_of_rooms - IFNULL(SUM(r.no_of_rooms),0) as "rooms available"  
FROM Roomtypes rt 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservation r ON r.roomtype_id = rt.id 
      AND '2018-04-11 10:00:00' >= r.check_in 
      AND '2018-04-12 09:59:59' <= r.check_out
GROUP BY rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms
```

[Here's an sqlfiddle example (MySQL 5.6) with create script](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8193ab/1).